# Pegar o subdomínio com PHP

Tags: php

Como faço para pegar o nome do subdomínio com PHP? Tentei da forma abaixo, mas ele me retorna o domínio principal:

```
$caminhoAbsoluto = $http . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/";
```

Por exemplo, tenho o seguinte subdomínio: `http://subdiretorio.site.com.br`, com o código acima, está trazendo da seguinte forma:

```
 http://site.com.br
```

e gostaria de pegar:

```
http://subdiretorio.site.com.br
```

Comment: Acredito que a variável `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` retorne ela completa, não?

Answer (score 1):

Se o virtualhost estiver bem configurado então `SERVER_NAME` deve funcionar bem, mas creio que o seu caso seja outro meio, como proxy-reverso ou então os hosts para suas aplicações são resolvidos pelo header `Host:` no HTTP.

Ou seja o valor de `SERVER_NAME` não é alterado, pois as variáveis `SERVER_` geralmente são valores fixos de configurações.

Então para resolver isto você terá que usar o `HTTP_HOST`, pois as as variáveis com prefixo `HTTP_` se baseiam nos headers.

O `SERVER_NAME` provavelmente não esta "configurado" para cada subdomínio especifico, ou seja o processo é dinâmico e não "fixo" dentro do VirtualHost, por exemplo se cada subdomínio estivesse definido com `ServerName` e `ServerAlias` o VirtualHost iria funciona corretamente, exemplo em Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dominio.com
    ServerAlias foo.dominio.com
    ServerAlias bar.dominio.com
    ServerAlias baz.dominio.com

    DocumentRoot /public
</VirtualHost>
```

**Mas provavelmente suas configurações são "dinâmicas"**, ou seja, os seus subdomínios seja resolvidos pelo header mesmo, então neste caso a variável `SERVER_NAME` só é populado com o alias do host principal, já que as demais **não devem existir nas configurações**, então o jeito é usar `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` que vai pegar o valor de `Host:`, como no exemplo quando solicitar a página no seu navegador isto vai ocorrer:

```
GET /foo/bar/baz HTTP/1.1
Host: subdominio.dominio.com
Connection: keep-alive
```

Então o valor de `Host:` que é no exemplo `subdominio.dominio.com`, será populado para o `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, ficando assim:

```
$caminhoAbsoluto = $http . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/";
```

> **Nota:** suponho que o `$http` você já tenha, para saber se é HTTP ou HTTPS, se não tiver ainda faça isto apenas:
>
> ```
>  $http = !empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? 'https://' : 'http://';
>
>  $caminhoAbsoluto = $http . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/";
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Utilize a variável `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, ela irá retornar o host completo, com subdomínio inclusive. Logo se usar o comando a seguir, terá o resultado que esperava:

```
echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; // Será impresso: http://subdiretorio.site.com.br
```

E para extrair somente o subdomínio da string, utilize o simples trecho de código a seguir:

```
echo explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])[0]; // Será impresso: subdiretorio
```

Answer (score 0):

Seria algo do tipo:

```
echo $caminhoAbsoluto = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/";
```

se quiseres apenas o subdominio usa o **[array_shift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)**:

```
$var = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
echo array_shift($var);
```

Comment: Caro 13dev, esse uso de explode pode até funcionar no php5.3, 5.4 e cia, mas no php7 com certeza vai falhar, pois `array_shift` espera uma referencia, causando algo como `PHP Notice:  Only variables should be passed by reference`, claro que no geral o PHP ignora e é só um Notice, mas ainda sim o objetivo é usar referencia e não valores em funções que esperam **referencias**: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.references.php

Comment: nem tinha notado, mas já editei a resposta, obrigado pelo aviso!

Answer (score -1):

Experimente essas funções para ver se resolve o teu problema:

```
<?php

// COMO COMPLEMENTO PARA PESQUISA DE PROTOCOLO HTTP OU HTTPS
// Apenas para fins de conhecimento
if( !function_exists('server_protocol') ){
    function server_protocol() {
        $protocol = $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'];
        if ( ! in_array( $protocol, array( 'HTTP/1.1', 'HTTP/2', 'HTTP/2.0' ) ) ) {
            $protocol = 'HTTP/1.0';
        }
        return $protocol;
    }
}

echo server_protocol() . "<br>";

#################################################################

// ENDERECO COMPLETO DO SITE COM PROTOCOLO, ENDERECO e /
if( !function_exists('urlbase') ) {
    function urlbase() {
        $protocol = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
        $query = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        $path = pathinfo( $query );
        $url = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/";
        return $url;
    }
}

echo urlbase() . "<br>";

#################################################################

?>
```

Comment: Serve para qualquer diretório, sendo ele também um subdiretório, retornará a URL completa.